# Service auto-scaling describe-scalable-targets not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-fargate

Currently have a cluster with a service created based on this cluster and load balancer / target group from creating it in the command prompt with `aws ecs create-service` and when running the command to describe my scalable targets as `aws describe-scalable-targets --resource-ids (fargate-service/default/fargate-clustr)` I receive an error `syntax error, unexpected token '('` so I assume I am inputting wrong syntax for trying to describe the targets.

Tells me on the site linked below for service-auto-scaling `specifying the resource ID of the ECS service associated with the scalable target in Application Auto Scaling` which I cannot find the resource ID for within my ECS service?

My scope is to create auto scaling for my tasks within my cluster.

Scalable-targets command I followed
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html#auto-scaling-IAM

Command for registering targets:

```
    --service-namespace ecs \
    --scalable-dimension ecs:service:DesiredCount \
    --resrouce-id fargate-service/default/fargate-cluster \
    --min-capacity 1 \
    --max-capacity 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command should be:

```
aws application-autoscaling  describe-scalable-targets --resource-ids fargate-service/default/fargate-clustr --service-namespace ecs
```

Comment: When running it returns an empty string, "Scalable Targets": [] meaning I have no targets setup, when registering as shown in the updated post, I execute that line of code and am returned back with "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the RegisterScalableTarget operation: Unsupported service namespace, resoruce type or scalable dimesion." even though I defined my resource-id service and cluster.

Comment: @AaronD Maybe you look at wrong region. Nevertheless if my answer was helpful to overcome the syntax errors, it's acceptance would be appreciated.

Comment: I haven't configured anything to do with a region though?

Comment: @AaronD you specify region using - - region option. If it doesn't help, please make new question, specific to the new issue.

Comment: I have a post up from yesterday in relation to the issue